# How to display data in textview automatically when i have finished inputting the ID field?

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit

so i have edittext & textview. edittext for NIK & textview for NAMA. the concept is when I have finished typing the NIK field, then at that moment the name data (NAMA) appears in the textview automatically based on database. I still confused how to do it properly.

Database Structure

| NIK | NAMA |
| --- | --- |
| 96296 | Farrasta |
| 94878 | Alfian |

Edit Text

```
etNik.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String data = etNik.getText().toString();
        if (data == NikKry){
            getNama();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Function for get NAMA

```
private void getNama(){
    APIRequestData armNama = RetroMaster.konekRetrofit().create(APIRequestData.class);
    Call<List<DataMaster>> tampilNama = armNama.ardGetNama(NikKry);

    tampilNama.enqueue(new Callback<List<DataMaster>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<DataMaster>> call, Response<List<DataMaster>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                tvNama.setText(response.body().get(0).getNAMA());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<DataMaster>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(TambahActivity.this, "Gagal "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `if (data == NikKry)` use `.equals()` to compare strings.

Comment: so it's means "if (data.equals(NikKry)" ?

Answer (score 0):

What kind database you use. You can send asyncTask with query params to mysql or mariadb database.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34631664)

Comment: Change the textview value 
then from onPostExecute by processing json string response on class extends asyncTask